# Session user in membership provider of asp.net mvc c#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

I am a pretty beginner developer with asp.net mvc c#, I am so wonder, when user log in using membership provider, where is the place that set the session of the user log in success or fail? When user log in success, I found is `this.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` set to true, But where is the place that set it to true?

Waiting for your answer.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

asp.net authentication module does that for you. you are not going to find that in your code, unless you wrote something custom in that area.

Comment: Thanks. But why asp.net authenticate module can know, whether the user log in or not yet?

Comment: the code behind the login button on your login page tells it to when it calls FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage. There are other similar alternatives - in case you don't find that exact line.

Comment: @titi: It uses the ASP.Net forms auth cookie

Answer (score 1):

When using asp.net membership the session cookie is set automatically by the provider. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fw3ef80%28v=vs.100%29.aspx, for some additional help.